# why am I getting this error windowed form?

Tags: c#, exception

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Cookie.Dozen'.  at Cookie.CookieSource.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender,  EventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 112
```

Line 112 is below:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dozen = (Dozen) this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
    this.CostChosenLb.ResetText();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I select one of the item from listbox, it's going to display price in textbox. But whenever I try to do that, I get above error. Help!

Comment: What is the type of `this.dozen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your's ListBox is bind to a string Type and not to a Dozen type. You should check how are you setting the ListBox Items property.

```
this.listBox1.Items = yoursList
```

You can try change your code to:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dozen = this.listBox1.SelectedItem as Dozen;
    this.CostChosenLb.ResetText();
}
```